# Sharepoint 2010: Move button disappears in site content and structure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I have a sub-site (http://mysite/documentcenter). My user is in Site Collection Administrators, so I can see and click the move button in site content and structure of sub-site.

But the other users, who has contribute access to all documents, can't see the Move button - it completely disappeared, it's not greyed out.

How can I make the move button display for the other users?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but, you need to have the following Permission Level enabled or Move is not available.

> *Manage Web Site  -  Grants the ability to perform all administration tasks for the Web site as well as manage content.*

I would be very careful assigning this permission though as it adds a whole slew of additional access for the user(s).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Add and Customize Pages permissions is present. There could be a Deny mask coming in from User Policy from central admin, which can overwrite Site Collection admin permissions.